# How to apply rolling t.test with pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, rolling-computation

Considering that I have this hypothetical dataset:

[image: hypothetical dataset].

I can't quite figure out how to apply rolling t.test on both given columns in the dataset, the way we can apply rolling mean with a give window.
What I aim to achieve is, with a t.test applied and based on H-Null being rejected, for every rejection I want to show "x" on the bottom of graph just like this:

[image: plot]

Answer (score 0):

Below is one potential implementation of this with some sample data. I chose a window of 5, but it could be whatever.

The important part is using [window operations](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/window.html), and then using a custom function with `.agg`.

```py
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import ttest_1samp


popmean = 0
sig_level = 0.05


my_data = pd.DataFrame({
    'time': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    'var_1': [2, 1, 5, 10, 15, 30, -10, 5, 4, 1],  
    'var_2': [5, 8, 4, -10, 50, 40, 45, 50, 4, 5],  
}).set_index('time')

def run_test(x, popmean):
    tscore, pvalue = ttest_1samp(x, popmean)
    return pvalue

rolling_fields = my_data \
    .filter(['var_1', 'var_2']) \
    .rolling(window=5).agg(run_test, popmean = popmean)\
    .rename(lambda x: f'{x}_t_test', axis='columns') 

rolling_fields['throw_flag'] = rolling_fields.min(axis=1).lt(sig_level)

result = pd.concat([my_data, rolling_fields], axis=1).reset_index()
result
```

|  | time | var_1 | var_2 | var_1_t_test | var_2_t_test | throw_flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 5 | NaN | NaN | False |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 8 | NaN | NaN | False |
| 2 | 3 | 5 | 4 | NaN | NaN | False |
| 3 | 4 | 10 | -10 | NaN | NaN | False |
| 4 | 5 | 15 | 50 | 0.065364 | 0.323683 | False |
| 5 | 6 | 30 | 40 | 0.072482 | 0.181021 | False |
| 6 | 7 | -10 | 45 | 0.199829 | 0.099326 | False |
| 7 | 8 | 5 | 50 | 0.199829 | 0.037304 | True |
| 8 | 9 | 4 | 4 | 0.255022 | 0.011973 | True |
| 9 | 10 | 1 | 5 | 0.412460 | 0.045627 | True |

### Making a plot

I'll use plotnine for this. Basically it is just two line graphs laid on top of each other, and then a scatter plot where points that shouldn't be flagged are plotted as an invisible point, and points that should be flagged are plotted as an 'x'.

```py
from plotnine import ggplot, geom_point, geom_line, aes, labs
from plotnine.themes import theme_classic
from plotnine.scales import scale_shape_manual, scale_y_continuous

marker_y_position = -25

(ggplot(result)
 + geom_line(aes('time', 'var_1'), 
             color = 'blue')
 + geom_line(aes('time', 'var_2'), 
             color = 'orange')
 + geom_point(aes('time', marker_y_position, shape = 'throw_flag'), 
              na_rm = True, 
              color = 'red', 
              size = 4,
              show_legend = False)
 + scale_shape_manual(['', 'x'])
 + plotnine.themes.theme_classic()
 + labs(title = 'Analysis of Important Variables', x = 'Time', y = 'Centralized Value')
)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much. Would you please be kind enough and guide me with the second part of this question?

Comment: Added! Also changed around the original code a bit to make the plotting easier.