# Applying Scipy's ttest Using a Rolling Window - Part 2

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, rolling-computation

My question tackles a slightly different angle of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67853520/how-to-apply-rolling-t-test-with-pandas) question:

I have a helper function which computes scipy's ttest for independence. Here it is:

```
# Helper Function for Testing for Independence

def conduct_ttest(data, variable_1="bias", variable_2="score", nan_policy="omit"):
    
    test_result = ttest_ind(data[variable_1], data[variable_2], nan_policy=nan_policy)
    test_statistic = test_result[0]
    p_value = test_result[1]
    
    return test_statistic, p_value
```

I would like to run it using a 5 period rolling window so that it outputs the test results into the dataframe, "data". The dataframe looks like this:

```
date       bias score
1/1/2021    5   1000
1/2/2021    13  1089
1/3/2021    21  1178
1/4/2021    29  1267
1/5/2021    37  1356
1/6/2021    45  1445
1/7/2021    53  1534
1/8/2021    61  1623
1/9/2021    69  1712
1/10/2021   77  1801
1/11/2021   85  1890
1/12/2021   93  1979
1/13/2021   101 2068
1/14/2021   109 2157
1/15/2021   117 2246
1/16/2021   125 2335
1/17/2021   133 2424
```

What I have tried:

```
data[["test_statistic", "p_value"]] = \
data.rolling(5).apply(lambda x: conduct_ttest(x, variable_1="bias", variable_2="score", nan_policy="omit")
```

However, it is not working. Does anyone have tips on what I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I failed to find a buit-in `rolling` method, so try this simple iterative workaround solution:

```
#in this function I just added index to returning values:
def conduct_ttest(data, variable_1="bias", variable_2="score", nan_policy="omit"):
    test_result = ttest_ind(data[variable_1], data[variable_2], nan_policy=nan_policy)
    test_statistic = test_result[0]
    p_value = test_result[1]
    return data.index.max(), test_statistic, p_value

#define rolling apply period:
window = 5 

pd.DataFrame(
    [conduct_ttest(df.iloc[range(i,i+window)]) for i in range(len(df)-window)],
    columns=['index','test_statistic','p_value']
).set_index('index', drop=True)
```

result:

```
       test_statistic       p_value
index                              
4          -18.310951  8.140624e-08
5          -19.592876  4.788281e-08
6          -20.874800  2.909324e-08
7          -22.156725  1.819271e-08
8          -23.438650  1.167216e-08
9          -24.720575  7.663247e-09
10         -26.002500  5.136947e-09
11         -27.284425  3.509024e-09
12         -28.566349  2.438519e-09
13         -29.848274  1.721420e-09
14         -31.130199  1.232845e-09
15         -32.412124  8.947394e-10
```